# Can any identify the mistake in my algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming

The problem statement is like this

Given a binary matrix, find out the maximum size square sub-matrix with all 1s.

For example, consider the below binary matrix.

```
   0  1  1  0  1 
   1  1  0  1  0 
   0  1  1  1  0
   1  1  1  1  0
   1  1  1  1  1
   0  0  0  0  0
```

The maximum square sub-matrix with all set bits is 3

I have created one memoization based dp solution

My program is

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define R 6
#define C 5

int getmaxsizesummatrix(int mat[R][C],vector< vector<int> > &v,int r,int c)
{
    if(r<0||c<0)
        return 0;

    if(r==0||c==0)
    {
        v[r][c]=mat[r][c];
         return mat[r][c];
    }


    if(v[r][c]==-1)
    {
    int m=INT_MIN;
    int flag=1;
        for(int j=0;j<=r;j++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<=c;k++)
            {

                int x,y,z;
                x = getmaxsizesummatrix(mat,v,j-1,k-1);
                y = getmaxsizesummatrix(mat,v,j-1,k);
                z = getmaxsizesummatrix(mat,v,j,k-1);



                if(mat[j][k]==1)
                {
                m=max(m,min(x,min(y,z))+1);
                }
                else
                {    
                 m=max(m,min(x,min(y,z)));   
                }
            }
        }
    return v[r][c] = m;
    }
    else
    {
        return v[r][c];
    }
}

int main()
{
    int M[R][C] = {{0, 1, 1, 0, 1},
                   {1, 1, 0, 1, 0},
                   {0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
                   {1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
                   {1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
    vector< vector<int> > v(R+1,vector<int>(C+1,-1));
  cout<<getmaxsizesummatrix(M,v,6,5);
  return 0;
}
```

I am getting 4 as output.

can any one correct my approach???

Comment: Practicing for CodeJam?

Comment: Please use a debugger and check your variable content step by step....it will be more efficient than posting your code here.

Comment: learning dp..not for codejam @MarwanAlani

Comment: I run your code in ideone.com and gives me 5 instead of 4...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code a bit to make it works

Here is the explanation: You have 2 problems when implementing the DP solution

1. Definition of the dp vector `v[][]`
2. You mix up bottom-up & top-down implementation and make it even harder to debug

For the `<` vs `<=` as the other answer mentioned, that is not a problem in your implementation as it is *abnormal implementation* which said as point 2 above, but you have to pass `R-1` & `C-1` to the function instead so you still calculate `v[r][c]` without going out of bound

I will focus on the above two points.

For 1, can you tell me what is your definition of `v[][]`?
Is it **the maximum square length found so far** or **the maximum square length which square's bottom-right corner is (i,j)**? This is a huge difference of choice, and as you are using `v[][]` to recursively calculate another `v[][]`, you should adopt the second option, which is part of code I modify for you. For example, your code will give `1` at `v[1][2] & v[1][4]` (0-based), while mine will give `0` as `mat[1][2] & mat[1][4]` is `0` and CANNOT form any squares. After modification, now your code will compute `v[][]` which adopts the second definition, so we have to loop through whole `v[][]` to get the answer instead of simply print `v[R][C]`

For 2, your implementation is a bit messy, because you mix up bottom-up & top-down implementation. In another words, you mixed up **for-loop iteration** & **recursion**, for most of the DP problems including this one, you only need to choose either one approach but not both. You are trying recursion approach, which call `Function(R,C)` to get the answer, but in each call, you loop through the array every time which is redundant and error-prone. You should either

1. Bottom-up: Don't use function at all, no recursion, simply set base case (row 1), and use two for-loops shown in your code to build `v[][]` from small index to big index
2. Top-down: Use recursion, no for loop inside the recursive function!! Just write something like `Func(R,C) = max(Func(R-1,C-1), Func(R-1,C), Func(R,C-1))+1` with base case to guard the negative index, already computed `v[r][c]` etc.

Please have a look of the code and tell me if there is anything missed or unclear, I will explain more if needed.

```js
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define R 6
#define C 5

int getmaxsizesummatrix(int mat[R][C],vector< vector<int> > &v,int r,int c)
{
    if(r<0||c<0)
        return 0;

    if(r==0||c==0)
    {
        v[r][c]=mat[r][c];
         return mat[r][c];
    }


    if(v[r][c]==-1)
    {
  int m=INT_MIN;
        for(int j=0;j<=r;j++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<=c;k++)
            {
                int x,y,z;
             x = getmaxsizesummatrix(mat,v,j-1,k-1);
             y = getmaxsizesummatrix(mat,v,j-1,k);
             z = getmaxsizesummatrix(mat,v,j,k-1);
             
   
                if(mat[j][k]==1)
                {
                 m=max(m,min(x,min(y,z))+1);
                }
                else
                {    
                  m=max(m,min(x,min(y,z)));   
                }
            }
        }
        if(mat[r][c] == 0) return v[r][c] = 0; // <-- Add this line
        return v[r][c] = m;
     
    }
    else
    {
        return v[r][c];
    }
}

int main()
{
    int M[R][C] = {{0, 1, 1, 0, 1},
                   {1, 1, 0, 1, 0},
                   {0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
                   {1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
                   {1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
   vector< vector<int> > v(R+1,vector<int>(C+1,-1));
  
  getmaxsizesummatrix(M,v,R-1,C-1);  // <-- Change Parameter
  

  // Change the answer-optain code 
  int ans = INT_MIN;
  for(int i=0; i<R; i++) 
   for(int j=0; j<C;j++) ans = max(ans, v[i][j]);
  
  cout << ans << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @shole for the answer and nice explanation.

Comment: @sai No problem, glad that help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of this, but by the looks of it - you're off by one.

Notice:

```
#define R 6
#define C 5
...
int M[R][C] = {...};
getmaxsizesummatrix(M,v,6,5); 
...
int getmaxsizesummatrix(int mat[R][C],vector< vector<int> > &v,int r,int c) // r=6, c=5
{
    ...
    for(int j=0;j<=r;j++)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<=c;k++)
        {
             ...
        }
    }
}
```

Perhaps the solution is to check strictly for `j<r` rather than `j<=r`.